# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch creates a new stacking context on elements without z-index

Tags: css, scroll, ios8, ios6, z-index

**Problem**

iOS 6 seems to create a new stacking context for every descendent with `position` other than `static` regardless if `z-index` is set or not.

Does anyone know if this is normal expected behaviour, or is this a bug in the way `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` interferes with stacking order?

**Example**

See code below, or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycsuY/)

Both `row` elements have position `relative`, but no `z-index`. Both Google Chrome and Safari on my laptop render the blue 'sub-menu' on top of the second `row`.

When the example is being tested on the iOS simulator, the 'sub-menu' is rendered behind the second `row`. After removing the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` it renders just as I expect.

It seems to me adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` creates a new stacking context for every descendent with a position set other then `static` regardless if `z-index` is set.

```
<style>
    div.content {
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    div.row {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background: red;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    div.sub {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        A
        <div class="sub">
            Sub menu of A<br>
            Sub menu of A<br>
            Sub menu of A<br>
            Sub menu of A<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        B
    </div>
</div>
```

```

** Additional note **
I'd like to tag this post with '-webkit-overflow-scrolling' but I do not have enough reputation to create a new one.

Comment: This appears to be fixed on iOS9

Comment: I am on iOS11 and it still does add a stacking context. Obviously it is not a bug:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/14#issuecomment-8075213
I must say that I really struggle with this and to me it is a rather buggy thing, which I could not fix so far...